# Initialize JQuery UI

Tags: html, jquery-ui

I've been trying to use Jquery UI, and I keep getting confused by it.  So I've put together a minimal test-case here.
http://jsfiddle.net/vmZap/
Basically, I include JQUERY, JQUERY-UI, and the JQUERY-UI CSS file.  Then I put this code on the page:

```
<button>Button</button>
```

Based on my reading, that button, should show up with the Jquery UI Signature look (complete with style and markup changes).  As you can see in my fiddle, it doesn't.  Is there some sort of call I'm missing that I need to use to initialize jquery-ui to try to do something rather than just sitting there?

I have been fiddling with this stuff for days, but when a test-case as simple as this doesn't work, I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the jquery-ui button on all button elements, then in the `onDomReady` you need to add:

```
​$('button').button();
```

This will apply the jquery-ui button styles to all elements matching your selector, in this case all `button` elements.

Comment: @deltree you're not an idiot, and there are no dumb questions.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't worked much with jQuery-UI, but don't you need a JS call to make the button look different?

```
$("button").button();
```